# Ionic - ATM styles decimal places

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I've found one [example](http://jsfiddle.net/77bMx/86/) in jQuery. Like what I want, but i'm not much familiar with jQuery, so 90% code I'm not understand. For example `e.keyCode`, I'm not understand at all. So it's difficult for me to change it to normal javascript (ionic). Can anyone help me. Thanks.

Comment: This question is really not related to ionic. Anyways, why don't you just use the code you found which actually works? there is no problem using jQuery and ionic together, actually Angular (which ionic builds upon) contains a subset of jQuery called jQuery lite. Anyways if you want to do this the Angular(ionic) way then you should look in to filters https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: @iCediCe Thanks for your comment, I dont want to use jQuery because, all my code currently is in javascript. Then I want to change that code from jQuery to javascript.

Comment: But jQuery IS javascript... but I get why you don't want to use jQuery, a quick glance at the code tells me that theres not a lot you jQuery being used there, shuld be fairly easy to rewrite to vanilla. Chek out this, it might help you on the way: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'm already finish that. :)

Comment: You should post your solution for future reference.